# Subversion switch problems - Windows OK, Ubuntu Not!

Tags: svn, ubuntu, branching-and-merging

I've got a repository i've been working with a little, it has around 805 revisions of a web site.

From the beginning of the project it was envisioned that once we have made it a short way through development we would break off in to multiple branches, one for the basic framework, and initially one for the first web site based on that framework.  Eventually there will be further web sites based on the framework.

I've just created two branches baed upon the HEAD revision, one called "Framework" and one called "Site".

I had two working copies, one on an ubuntu Dev server.  This is where i was doing most of the dev work, but i also had another working copy on a windows machine.  This was used for the design side of things.

So far this has worked perfectly, both working copies can commit happily to the trunk.

The big problem i have is that now i have the branches, the windows machine can access the branches, but the ubuntu machine gives the error:

```
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

One the windows machine i am using TortoiseSVN, and the ubuntu machine is the subversion command line.

The repository is located at:

```
http://192.168.1.251/svn/project
```

With the trunk at:

```
http://192.168.1.251/svn/project/trunk
```

and the branches at:

```
http://192.168.1.251/svn/project/branches/Framework
http://192.168.1.251/svn/project/branches/Site
```

The command i am using to switch my ubuntu machines working copy to another branch (say the Framework branch) is:

```
svn switch http://192.168.1.251/svn/project/branches/Framework
```

Which as i mentioned above returns:

```
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

Can anyone shed any light on why the Windows machine can access the branches ok, but the Ubuntu client can't?

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but I have some bad experience in Windows/ Linux SVN: Linux is case-sensitive, while Windows is not. So a folder "name" in Windows can be accessed as "Name", but Linux returns errors since it can't find "Name".

Comment: your folder is named "Framework" or "framework"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it would either be a permissions issue or a case-sensitivity issue. Check the permissions of each branch and make sure that the Ubuntu user has access to read/write to them. If it is a case-sensitivity issue, that should be pretty straightforward to fix.

Comment: Perfect! I had titled the branches with capital first letters, i tried again with the correct path (cases correct) and it checked out perfectly!!!